# mount error, special device does not exists

Tags: linux, mount

I have a linux Debian server:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy)
Release:    7.1
Codename:   wheezy
```

I have some hard devices attached to my server that are mounted in my system in different directories.
Every things worked ok until a device was physically unplugged from the server without being umouted.
After connecting the device once again, I tired to mount it:
This is my `/etc/fstab` file content(this is the first configuration of the device and it used to work):

```
/dev/cciss/c0d1p1         /var/www/vhosts/    ext4        defaults,acl    0       1
/dev/cciss/c0d2p1       /home/samba/        ext4    defaults,acl    0       1
```

My cciss device contains:(`ls /dev/cciss/`)

```
c0d0  c0d0p1  c0d0p2  c0d0p5  c0d1  c0d2  c0d2p1
```

I wanted to mount `/dev/cciss/c0d1p1` so I tried:

```
mount /dev/cciss/c0d1p1
```

and I get this output:

```
mount: special device /dev/cciss/c0d1p1 does not exist
```

`fdisk -l` shows no entry for `/dev/cciss/c0d1` also `blkid` gaves me:

```
/dev/cciss/c0d0p5: UUID="4d144db1-bypl-43d0-b5cb-e857ab8b7f14" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/cciss/c0d2p1: UUID="d0fdfteb-e9eb-4t8c-bf5e-374613e29btr" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1: UUID="78sa9u1d-8d17-44be-9116-758ez1k24d27" TYPE="ext4"
```

I tried `fdisk -l /dev/cciss/` and it gives me this output:

```
last_lba(): I don't know how to handle files with mode 40755
```

`pvs -a` shows me an error during reading the device `/dev/cciss/c0d1`. Output:

```
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 750122696704: Input/output error
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 750122811392: Input/output error
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  PV                VG   Fmt Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/cciss/c0d0p5          ---     0     0 
  /dev/cciss/c0d1            ---     0     0 
  /dev/cciss/c0d2p1          ---     0     0 
  /dev/root                  ---     0     0
```

I didn't quite understood the problem but I think that once the device was disconnected, it have to be re-configured once again and I have to define the partitions before mounting the device.
I thought that maybe in my case the VolumeGroup name would be wrong so I tried :`lvscan`:

```
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 750122696704: Input/output error
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 750122811392: Input/output error
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  No volume groups found
```

also `pvscan; vgchange -ay` gaves me:

```
/dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 750122696704: Input/output error
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 750122811392: Input/output error
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  No matching physical volumes found
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 750122696704: Input/output error
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 750122811392: Input/output error
  /dev/cciss/c0d1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  No volume groups found
```

What this kind of input do mean? How to define a volume group to my device and more exactly what I am supposed to do before mounting my device?